# Prove that a subgroup of quaternion group of matrix is a normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be a complex number set.

Let $Q=${$I,A,A^2,A^3,B,BA,BA^2,BA^3=AB$}

s.t

GL(2,$\mathbb{C}$)={$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\\ \end{pmatrix}$|$ad-bc\neq0,a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{C}$}, and $Q$ is a subgroup of GL(2,$\mathbb{C}$),

$I=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\ \end{pmatrix}$, $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&i\\i&0\\ \end{pmatrix}$

Show that any subgroup of $Q$ is a normal subgroup.

How can I show this? I can't even start it.

Comment: I don't understand  the interest of situating this question in the quaternionic framework. $\mathbb{C}$ looks sufficient.